# Scala Future mapTo fails to compile because of missing ClassTag

Tags: scala, akka, future

Simple question, I have a problem where using mapTo on the result of ask results in a compiler error along the lines of:

```
not found: value ClassTag
```

For example:

```
(job ? "Run").mapTo[Result]
                   ^
```

I don't understand why it needs a ClassTag to do the cast? If I substitute a standard class from Predef like `String` as in `(job ? "Run").mapTo[String]` that compiles OK.

This happens when I define the class right above the line in question, as in:

```
class Result {}
(job ? "Run").mapTo[Result]
```

I still get the same problem.

Thanks, Jason.

I should also state that I'm using Scala 2.10.0 and Akka 2.1.0 (if that makes a difference).

Comment: Your code looks OK so far - so could you post the imports you used? Maybe an import is missing.

Comment: I just found a [comment](http://grokbase.com/p/gg/scala-language/126k8nt1fx/incompatibility-between-scala-2-10-m3-and-m4) about incompatibilities in the different Milestones of Scala 2.10.0. It suggests to `import reflect.ClassTag`. Try using Scala 2.10.1 and Akka 2.1.1 if that's an issue which has been fixed only recently.

Comment: @michael_s, genius, thanks for that, adding `import reflect.ClassTag` did the trick! Haven't tried updating Scala versions yet, bit loath to change package dependencies at this point in the development cycle. If you want to post your comment as an answer I can mark it correct and give u some status.

Comment: OK - added that for documentation purposes - feel free to give credits. Although I think this is a problem for very special circumstances. But anyway - I understand that the compiler error was not very helpful either.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to be a particular problem with the Scala 2.10.0 version

After adding

```
import reflect.ClassTag
```

the implicitly used `ClassTag` parameter in `mapTo` should work.

Either that or updating to a newer Version of Akka/Scala (which should be prefered if possible).

Comment: 2.10.1 was released about a week and a half ago (2013/3/13).

Comment: Still broken with Akka 2.1.2 and Scala 2.10.1, btw.

Comment: If you use generics I had to add `implicit arg tag: ClassTag[R]` as well. Example: `def reqReply[M, R]( message:M, process: R => Unit )( implicit tag: ClassTag[R] ) = ( myAkkaService ? message ).onComplete{ case Success( Some( r: R ) ) => process( r ) ... } // Simplified example`